# jquery not able validate second form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 forms on 1 page, one is the main one, the other is a form within a modal.  First one is the one asp.net brings in

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="dataclass.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

after that form closes i bring in the modal

```
   </form>

<!-- edit modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editDataClassModal" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="with: selectedTag">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="editDataClassForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data Classification</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 paddingTop3">
                                Classification:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="txtClassification" name="txtClassification" class="form-control" data-bind="value: copyname" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnCancelEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSaveEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize">Save</button>
                    <div class="marginTop10">
                        <span class="label-danger" id="lblErrorEdit" style="display: none;">An error occurred while saving this record.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Problem is I'm not able to get the second form to validate, my validation code is

```
            $(document).on("click", "#btnSaveEdit", function () {
            var form = $("#editDataClassForm");
            form.validate();
            if (form.valid()) {
                // always goes in here
            }
        });


            $("#editDataClassForm").validate({
            rules: {
                txtClassification: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtClassification: {
                    minlength: "Classification must consist of at least 2 characters"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
                label.addClass('errorText');
                label.insertAfter(element);
            },
            wrapper: 'span'
        });
```

Comment: One big problem is that you effectively call `$("#editDataClassForm").validate` twice.  It only gets called once (with your rules/options) for initialization.  Any subsequent calls are always ignored.

Comment: You mean the code that is var form = $("#editDataClassForm");            form.validate(); should i remove those two lines?

Comment: yes, you cannot call `.validate()` twice on same form.